# Grok custom pattern

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I have the simple message coming in my logstash:

```
2018-09-30 20:25:07.708  INFO 8013 --- [nio-8443-exec-3] c.e.demo.controller.UsuarioController    : INICIO CHAMADA | 311
```

I want to remove the following field from this message.

```
"311"
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there. You simply need to escape the pipe `|` character with a backslash (otherwise it matches the `801` after `INFO`), like this:

```
: INICIO CHAMADA \| (?<identificador_chamada>[0-9]{3})
                 ^
                 |
             add this
```

and you'll get this

```
{
  "identificador_chamada": [
    "311"
  ]
}
```